# How to extract config value from env variable with clap derive?

Tags: rust, clap

I cannot find in the docs how to set this up. Let's say I have

```
#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
pub struct Opts {
    #[clap(long)]
    dry_run: bool,
}
```

What do I need to do to get dry_run from APP_DRY_RUN env variable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to enable the `env` feature:

`Cargo.toml`

```ini
...

clap = { version = "...", features = ["env"] }
```

Then you have to add the `env` clap derive option, which will by default read from an ALLCAPS recased env var:

```rust
#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
pub struct Opts {
    #[clap(long, env)]
    dry_run: bool, // --dry-run or DRY_RUN env var
}
```

Comment: ty. don't know why it was so hard for me to find that I need the `env` feature